# Is it possible to open a new terminal inside VSCode from inside a script?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to start 3 servers from a single command.

I have `package.json` scripts like so:

```
"serve_auth": "cd dev/mock/auth && nodemon --exec babel-node ./server.js --presets @babel/env",
"serve_db": "cd dev/mock/db && nodemon --exec babel-node ./server.js --presets @babel/env",
"start": "react-scripts start",
"develop": "./launch_script.sh"
```

and I have a script `launch_script.sh` like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

( yarn serve_db ) & ( yarn serve_auth ) & ( yarn start )
```

but this opens them all in a single terminal window, and they end up tripping all over each other.

I know you can open new terminals from the VSCode GUI, but is it possible to open a new terminal from within one?  Or to tell VSCode to open 3 terminals each with a separate command ?

Comment: Did compound tasks / launch configs work for you?

Comment: @DAXaholic not yet, I'm still working on it - will definitely be back to accept/upvote if I can get it working.  Problem is, my servers are written in ES6 so I need to transpile with babel first... which is a problem because I'm running WSL inside VSCode on a Win10 machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this could be something for [compound tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks)

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Client Build",
            "command": "gulp",
            "args": ["build"],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/client"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Server Build",
            "command": "gulp",
            "args": ["build"],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/server"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "dependsOn": ["Client Build", "Server Build"]
        }
    ]
}
```

> Compound tasks
>   You can also compose tasks out of simpler tasks with
>   the dependsOn property. For example, if you have a workspace with a
>   client and server folder and both contain a build script, you can
>   create **a task that starts both build scripts in separate terminals**. If
>   you list more than one task in the dependsOn property, they are
>   executed in parallel by default.

Also [compound launch configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations) may be interesting to you as it seems like your scripts are for starting a frontend and backend app.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Server",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Client",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/client.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Server/Client",
            "configurations": ["Server", "Client"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Both are examples from the corresponding docs page but adjusting them to your scripts should be straightforward.